# Looking for a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am looking for a regular expression for following condition:

Input - String of any length

Output - Return true if string contains EXACTLY 2 upper case characters OR string contains EXACTLY 2 digits.

True cases

SS22

S5834534P

1ffgdfjdfS2

False cases

123SSS

SSSSSS

+++1++++1++++3

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where is your effort?  What language or tool are you using?

Comment: We know how to do for individual cases (2 digits, 2 upper case characters) but don't know how to take OR condition into account. We are using C#. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
egrep '^(([^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*)|([^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*))$' test.txt
```

The idea is, if you want to find matches with exactly two characters, you need to find strings with:

- Beginning
- 0 or more *wrong* characters (e.g., not digits)
- exactly one needed character (digit)
- 0 or more *wrong* characters (not digits)
- exactly one needed character (digit)
- 0 or more *wrong* characters (not digits)
- End

**EDIT**

Shorter form:

```
egrep '^(([^A-Z]*([A-Z][^A-Z]*){2})|([^0-9]*([0-9][^0-9]*){2}))$' test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks hudolejev ! What will be the modified expression for this case : either exactly 2 digits or exactly 2 uppercase strings but NOT both scenarios. For example - 22SS is not valid as both conditions are true. 22SSS is valid as only 1 condition is true.

Comment: '(^([^A-Z]*([A-Z][^A-Z]*){2}$)|(^[^0-9]*([0-9][^0-9]*){2})$)'  Move your string boundaries to each subexpression.

Comment: What you need here is `XOR` instead of `OR`. In theory, this can be achieved by subtracting subset of *digit-**and**-letter* matches from a set of all matches. As for this regex, `OR` is easy but `AND` is hard. I'd do it in two runs: first is given above, second is `egrep '^([^A-Z]*([A-Z][^A-Z]*){2})$' test.txt | egrep '^([^0-9]*([0-9][^0-9]*){2})$'` << this will give you all lines that contain both two-letters and two-numbers. You'll have to exclude these from the first set of matches. Sorry for being too Bash-specific in C# thread (: